# PHP: Gethostbyname and domain containing a number

Tags: php, dns, ip, gethostbyname

EDIT: The issue ended up being filtering software on the machine I was working on.

Using gethostbyname and domainname.com I can get the IP of but if it is say 1domain.com or doma1n.com it fails.
Also dns_get_record seems to behave the same way.

Is there an alternative to be able to source the ip for a domain containing numbers?

Comment: I've just tried `print_r(gethostbyname("1domain.com"));` and it gives `14.63.216.242`.  Can you show the actual code you are using which may help.

Comment: `doma1n.com` fails because it does not resolve to an IP.

Comment: Thank you both, I've edited the question. Turns out it was filtering software on the machine I was using. anyber - the doma1n.com and 1domain.com were meant to be just examples of the issue.